# Can rebuilding an index create fragmentation?

Tags: sql-server, index, index-tuning

Its my understanding that when you rebuild an index SQL will sort the pages into order at the end of the data file, growing the data file until all pages are ordered and then drop the old index leaving empty noncontiguous extents in the data file.

What then happens when you rebuild a second index? Does SQL perform the same action, growing the data file or does it move the second index into the old fragmented extents left behind by the first index? If it uses the old extents then would the rebuild create a new physically fragmented index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, SQL Server does not necessarily allocate extents (and mixed extent pages) for the rebuilt index at the end of the data file(s). Otherwise, the data file(s) would grow unnecessarily. SQL Server will allocate space from existing free extents when possible regardless of where they reside in the data file. See [Pages and Extents Architecture Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/pages-and-extents-architecture-guide) for more information on extent management.

All of the original index space becomes unallocated after an index rebuild. Even if the old index was fragmented (logical/physical order different), the resultant free space might be contiguous afterward, depending on where the extents reside happen to reside in the file(s). Subsequent space allocations can reuse this space.

To answer the question asked in the title of your question, a freshly (re)built index may be fragmented due to a parallel plan. One can specify MAXDOP 1 to avoid this. In the case of an existing index, REORGANIZE may be used instead.

Comment: Also certain indexes will generate a lot of fragmentation right after an index rebuild.  Classically a clustered index on a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER when rebuilt with fill factor of 100 will fragment quickly after the rebuild.